# What’s the difference between COPY and pg_dump —data-only

Tags: postgresql

I’m planning to migrate some tables out of existing database so the plan is to apply the schema on new database and then COPY data for each table.

What’s the difference of that versus pg_dump the data and then pg_restore?

Would copy needs restablishing indexes etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_dump --data-only` will produce a complete SQL script that can be run with `psql`. That script contains both the `COPY` statement and the data:

```
COPY laurenz.data_2020 (id, d, x) FROM stdin;
1499906 2020-11-07 13:26:00 x
1499907 2020-11-07 13:27:00 x
1499908 2020-11-07 13:28:00 x
\.
```

So it is all in one, and there is no danger that you restore a file to the wrong table, for example.

Other that convenience, there is no fundamental difference to running `COPY` directly.

Comment: thank you! It seems if i do pg_restore it will check some other constraints etc, which in our case is not our intention to check existing data. so maybe `COPY` works better

Comment: Not sure what you mean - but choose the option that is most convenient to you.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `pg_dump --data-only` it will output the data as `COPY` statements, unless you override with `--inserts` or  `--column-inserts`. So there is no difference in that case. In either case if the tables in the new database where not created with indexes they would need to be added.  You could solve that with either `-s -t <some_table>` to get just the table schema or `-t <some_table>` to get the table schema and data.

Comment: thank you! yes I plan to do a schema migration on the new DB first to match the original schema and then do `COPY`

Comment: Why not just do `pg_dump -FC -d <db_name> -f <db_name>.out`  then `pg_restore -d postgres -C  <db_name.out`. Where in `pg_restore` `-d` is the initial database to connect to and `-C` creates the database you dumped.

Comment: the destination database is already there with some tables and i only need some tables from the source table so need some surgery with pruning constraints etc before migrating data